# What does 'in a frozen sort of way' mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Could you please explain the meaning of the following sentence?

> It was winter and it was beautiful in a frozen sort of way.

In particular, what is the meaning of 'in a frozen sort of way'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is conversational register, not formal writing.

**sort of way** is a periphrasis for "way, manner, mode, style, look, appearance".

It was beautiful *in the way that frozen winter is beautiful*.  It might be inhospitable to life, but there is a kind of pristine icy splendor.

**sort of way** is a form of *qualification*:

> It was beautiful, in a predator-and-prey sort of way.

That is, *to the extent that* the predator-prey relationship in nature has a kind of beauty,  then it was beautiful.

> He was rather welcoming, in a grumpy old man sort of way.

Comment: Need to be careful, "***in a frozen sort of way***", is in a wintry fashion, "***in a Frozen sort of way***" is in reference to the Disney movie.

Comment: And in that case it would mean "To the extent that the movie *Frozen* is beautiful, it was beautiful rather in the way that *Frozen* is beautiful."